# Solve piecewise function

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, piecewise

I have two piecewise function

```
equ1 = Piecewise[{{0.524324 + 0.0376478x, 0.639464 <= x <= 0.839322}}]
equ2 = Piecewise[{{-0.506432 + 1.48068x, 0.658914 <= x <= 0.77085}}]
```

Now, I am trying to solve `equ1 = equ2`.

Firstly I tried `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[equ1 == equ2, x]
```

But the output is `x = 0`. I can only get the correct answer by set search starting point `0.7`. How can I direct get the answer without set starting point?

Secondly, I tried code Reduce:

```
Reduce[equ1 == equ2, x]
```

However, the error appear. The good news is `Reduce` do provide the correct answer for my equation. The error is:

```
Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
```

Do I have other way to solve those two piecewise function?

Comment: What's wrong with `Solve[0.524324 + 0.0376478 x == -0.506432 + 1.48068 x, x]`? or even `FindRoot[equ1 == equ2, {x, .7}]`?

Comment: Try to plot then you see where is root.`{Plot[equ1 - equ2, {x, 1/2, 1}], FindRoot[equ1 == equ2, {x, 7/10}]}`.

Comment: Because at later stages, I need to compara 100 equations to find out solution. It is not possible to set the starting value for each one of them.

Comment: Your `Reduce` command works for me.  The message is just a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 6):

Either:

```
FindRoot[equ1 == equ2, {x, 0.7, 0.639464, 0.839322}]
(*  {x -> 0.714299}  *)
```

Or:

```
NSolve[equ1 == equ2 && 0.639464 <= x <= 0.839322, x]
```

> `NSolve::ratnz`:.... *[Unimportant warning.]*

```
(*  {{x -> 0.714299}}  *)
```

*Update:*
Here's a programmatic way to get the interval of support and a starting point for `FindRoot`, assuming that by [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184824/solve-piecewise-function/184831#comment481956_184824), the OP means that they have to do this a hundred times:

```
equAll = {equ1, equ2};
{funAll, domAll} = Transpose@ equAll[[All, 1, 1]];
support = Simplify[And @@ domAll];
endpoints = First@ RegionBounds@ ImplicitRegion[support, x];
midpoint = Mean@ endpoints;  (* can be used as a starting point *)
```

**Alternatively,** if you can define your piecewise functions to be undefined outside the interval of support, then `Solve` can be used directly:

```
pw1 = Piecewise[{{0.524324 + 0.0376478 x, 0.639464 <= x <= 0.839322}}, Undefined];
pw2 = Piecewise[{{-0.506432 + 1.48068 x, 0.658914 <= x <= 0.77085}}, Undefined];

Solve[pw1 == pw2, x]
(*  {{x -> 0.714299}}  *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
equ1 = Rationalize[
  Piecewise[{{0.524324 + 0.0376478 x, 0.639464 <= x <= 0.839322}}]]
equ2 = Rationalize[
  Piecewise[{{-0.506432 + 1.48068 x, 0.658914 <= x <= 0.77085}}]]
Reduce[equ1 == equ2, x]
x == 0.714299 || x < 79933/125000 || x > 419661/500000
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have 100 equations and you want to find the unique solution to the whole set and each of your `Piecewise` are written in exactly the same form as the two you showed and the solution must lie in the intersection of all those inequalities then perhaps

```
equ1 = Piecewise[{{0.524324 + 0.0376478 x, 0.639464 <= x <= 0.839322}}];
equ2 = Piecewise[{{-0.506432 + 1.48068 x, 0.658914 <= x <= 0.77085}}];
funs = {equ1, equ2};
Join[{Equal @@ Map[#[[1, 1, 1]] &, funs]},
  {Max[Map[#[[1, 1, 2, 1]] &, funs]] < x < Min[Map[#[[1, 1, 2, 3]] &, funs]]}]
```

will give you

```
{0.524324 + 0.0376478 x == -0.506432 + 1.48068 x, 0.658914 < x < 0.77085}
```

and

```
x /. Solve[
  Join[{Equal @@ Map[#[[1, 1, 1]] &, funs]},
    {Max[Map[#[[1, 1, 2, 1]] &, funs]] < x < Min[Map[#[[1, 1, 2, 3]] &, funs]]}]
  , x][[1]]
```

will give you

```
0.714299
```

You can make the list of funs longer and longer and still get the solution.

The `Max` part of that is extracting all your lower bounds and finding the largest one. The `Min` part of that is extracting all your upper bounds and finding the smallest one. The `Equal` part of that is extracting all your equations and setting them equal to each other. We assemble those pieces and give them to Solve.

You should check carefully to make certain that there will always be one unique solution to your set of equations.

You might click on `Piecewise` and then `Details` in the help pages and read very carefully all the information there. Because you have not given any other information about the value of your functions if x happens to be outside the bounds you have given then the value of that `Piecewise` function will be zero for x outside those bounds. That might surprise you.